# Trying to scrub a file with AutoIt

Tags: search, append, line, autoit

I work with a piece of software that outputs a sql script during upgrades.  I am trying to make a tool that will read the file and append " ON IndexDataFile" to the lines that contain "CREATE INDEX" or "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX"
I open that file and write each line to a new file using FileOpen and FileReadLine.  Despite a good deal of searching via Google and specific forums I have not been able to figure out how to search each line and append to it when one of the two values are found.

Here is the loop I am using to write to the new file:

```
  While 1
    $line_read = FileReadLine($handle_read)
      If @error Then ExitLoop
    ;Code to evaluate line and append text when true
    FileWriteLine($handle_write, $line_read)
  WEnd
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to test the string and append when needed or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it with the following:

```
While 1
  $line_read = FileReadLine($handle_read)
  If @error Then ExitLoop
  If StringRegExp ( $line_read, "CREATE INDEX") Then $line_read = $line_read & " ON IndexData"
  If StringRegExp ( $line_read, "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX") Then $line_read = $line_read & " ON IndexData"
  FileWriteLine($handle_write, $line_read)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line it would be as easy as:

```
$line_read = StringRegExpReplace($line_read, "(CREATE\ (?:UNIQUE\ )?INDEX)", "\1 ON IndexData")
```

You can test your RegEx on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iA4fZ9/1) to make sure, it works as expected.

Or you can write your expression differently if you prefer it fo a better way of reading with an "or" symbol `|`:

```
$line_read = StringRegExpReplace($line_read, "(CREATE\ INDEX|CREATE\ UNIQUE\ INDEX)", "\1 ON IndexData")
```